# Scalable and flexible framework for e commerce website based on PHP or Django

Tags: php, python, e-commerce, customization

I have to build an **e commerce website** that aims to target very heavy traffic 2 to 3 years down the lane. I am comfortable with **PHP or Python**.

I would like to know what would be the best framework that I should use? Which solution would offer the scalability and ease of development? Moreover I would like the framework to be totally **customizable**. I have looked at various frameworks such as Magneto, OpenCart, PrestaShop, zen cart and loads of more. But frankly I can't understand well enough any of them until I dwell into the development.

But I cannot afford to waste time by experimenting with these solutions. I would like to know whether I should go for any framework at all?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: you should def use a framework. why reinvent the wheel? Groups or professionals with years of experience have made tools that can help you get off the ground faster, why wouldn't you use them?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You talk about using a framework, but the ones you've mentioned are not frameworks, they are Content Management System(s). By the way, it depends on your needs: if you want to have something that completely suits your needs, then you should build your own application (maybe using a real framework, like Symfony). But, if you don't need all that control, then why should you bother with scripting?

Comment: Actually what I meant by framework was the development tool that I should you? What I want to know is that whether I should use some PHP framework with a PHP  based CMS or I should use the same in Python.

Moreover I need complete customizability at the view end, in order to make my site easily navigable and attractive. 

And why I asked about building my own development environment was because I am targeting heavy user flow and want to develop keeping the scales in mind

Comment: If your project depends on correctly choosing between PHP or Django; then the real problem you have is developers.  Neither of these platforms is in some way better for the problem you're describing; but a team that is *very proficient* in any one platform will succeed on that platform (even if that's Neither of these).

Comment: This question is very similar to "I need to build a house; but I don't have any tools, which would be better, electric tools or pneumatic?".  The answer is "You need carpenters that are already proficient with tools and know how to build a house"

Comment: Ok so now let us say I do not have any confusion regarding PHP or Python. We are good at Python so we go with that. Now I want to tell me whether I should use any CMS or not? Will it give me the flexibility to customize the user interface or not?

I am sorry I am novice in this field, but I really need to do this and my queries maybe a little ignorant right ow but your answers will help me a lot.

Comment: I think you need to have more grasp of programming before you aim that high. Try python with django, codeigniter with php. see how do you feel about them. Then start with small projects, as time goes by, you will know your limits and skills; but programming is learned step by step; there are no elevators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a Django based E commerce site, I would suggest Satchmo Project:

> http://www.satchmoproject.com/
>   Have you been looking for a solid open source framework to build your online store?
>
> Do you need a customized shopping cart or eccommerce application built with Python?
>
> Do you need to add a Django based shopping cart to an existing site?
>
> If you answer Yes, to any of these, then Satchmo might be the right tool for you. Satchmo's > mission is to use Django to create an open source framework for creating unique and robust > online stores. To provide maximum flexibility, Satchmo is licensed under the BSD license.